# Is the open method of XMLHttpRequest the only way to get "not asynchronous" errors?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

As an answer to a query I posted here about how to do file uploads, someone pointed me at [this GitHub project.](https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify) Unfortunately, it's broken in several ways, but it has 58 forks, so I picked one of the two most recent ones, [this one,](https://github.com/vanlong2k/uploadify) and it was fixed, mostly. But, it doesn't quite work because this error is returned in the Web Console:

```
Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.
```

However, when I looked at the code, the XMLHttpRequest object's open call looks to have hard-coded `TRUE`, or at least has an appropriately sounding variable in there - `c.async` which is in one of the min.js files - `c.async` is set via `c.async="async"`. (I've never seen that usage before so maybe that's the bug?) Here are the code snippets, from grep, and in the case of the "min" files, grep plus some copy/paste:

```
jquery.uploadifive.js:                            xhr.open(settings.method, settings.uploadScript, true);
jquery.uploadifive.js:                                xhr.open(settings.method, settings.uploadScript, true);
xhr.open(c.method,c.Y,true);
jquery.min.js: i.open(c.type,c.url,c.async,c.username,c.password):i.open(c.type,c.url,c.async);
jquery.uploadifive.min.js:
xhr.open(c.method,c.Y,true); xhr.open(c.method,c.Y,true);
```

(As an aside, the two "min.js files" sure look to be auto-generated somehow - or, is this just a quirk of this codeline? If so, that seems very odd to me. But if "this is a thing," if someone can point me to some to learn more about this, that'd be great.)

I tried editing jquery.min.js and changed the c.async attribute to be set to "true", but that didn't work. So now I'm thinking maybe there's some other XMLHttpRequest method that can cause an asynch-related error...

OK, that's what I know about it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning, but one that should be heeded in production code.

Comment: @Bergi OH! Well, it's not working! I just presumed that was why! Hmmm... Now I'm not sure what I should do!

Comment: @Bergi ...OK, so it's only a warning, but it's one that shouldn't be thrown! Ideas about that?

Comment: "*Is the open method of XMLHttpRequest the only way to get “not asynchronous” errors?*" - Yes, if that's all you want to know. `c.async = "async"` is definitely weird, looks like it should be `c.async = true` assuming that `c` refers to a `jQuery.ajax` options object.

Comment: "*To answer my question how to do file uploads, someone pointed me at this GitHub project, but it's broken in several ways*" - surely there are dozens of jQuery file upload plugins, and you should be able to find one that's not broken instead of trying to fix that particular one.

Comment: @Bergi Well, you answered my question, so if you make it an actual answer, I'll mark it as correct. Someone else might be puzzled by this someday, too.